# request.getparameter returns null value in JSP

Tags: jsp, url

I want to get the details from one page to another but first I´m checking if the requested parameters are correct. All the values come back correct, except for the `url2`. I want to concatenate the name of the database to the end of the `url2` but it returns `null`.

```
<%-- dbname = name of the database --%>
<%
    table1 = request.getParameter("tabla1"); 
    dbname = request.getParameter("bdnombre");
    createdb = request.getParameter("crearbd");
%>
<%-- Converting the code into STRING variables --%>
<%!
  Connection con_postgres, con_database;
    String table1;
    String dbname; 
    String createdb;
  String url2 = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+ dbname;
  Statement crear_bd, crear_tablas;
%>
```

[image: Screenshot of the results when executed]

I tried changing the attributes in the input but it still returns null at the end of the url, unless there is something I haven't tried yet.

```
<tr>
    <td>DB Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bdnombre" required placeholder="No spaces"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Create the DB:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="crearbd" required ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Table:</td>
    <td><textarea rows="6" cols="25" name="tabla1"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><center><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Crear BD"></center></td>
    <td><center><input type="reset" name="borrar"> </center> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a local variable that has the same name like in previous scriptlet but it's not initialized.

```
String dbname;
```